# sql request that send back all rows where there is an insertion or modification

Tags: mysql, sql

I work with mysql.  I have 5 tables table1, table2, table3, table4, table5. Each table has two fields ins (timestamp when there is an insertion) and mod (timestamp when there is a modification). I want to find all order_no (from table table1) for which there is a modification or insertion on one of the 5 tables. The following request does not work (it has for result only one row)

```
select co.order_no 
from table1 co 
JOIN table2 item 
    ON co.order_no = item.order_no 
JOIN table3 dimension 
    ON dimension.item_id = item.id 
JOIN table4 material 
    ON material.item_id = item.id 
JOIN table5 product 
    ON product.item_id = item.id
 where (co.ins >='2018-12-26 01:00:00' and co.ins <='2019-06-26 01:00:00') 
    or (co.mod >='2018-12-26 01:00:00' and co.mod <='2019-06-26 01:00:00')
    or (item.ins >='2018-12-26 01:00:00' and item.ins <='2019-06-26 01:00:00') 
    or (item.mod >='2018-12-26 01:00:00' and item.mod <='2019-06-26 01:00:00')
    or (dimension.ins >='2018-12-26 01:00:00' and dimension.ins <='2019-06-26 01:00:00') 
    or (dimension.mod >='2018-12-26 01:00:00' and dimension.mod <='2019-06-26 01:00:00')
    or (material.ins >='2018-12-26 01:00:00' and material.ins <='2019-06-26 01:00:00') 
    or (material.mod >='2018-12-26 01:00:00' and material.mod <='2019-06-26 01:00:00')
    or (product.ins >='2018-12-26 01:00:00' and product.ins <='2019-06-26 01:00:00') 
    or (product.mod >='2018-12-26 01:00:00' and product.mod <='2019-06-26 01:00:00')
order by co.id, item.id DESC;
```

indeed when I look at the insertion or modification on dimension, I have more than 200 row

```
select dimension.id 
from table3 dimension 
where (dimension.ins >='2018-12-26 01:00:00' and dimension.ins <='2019-06-26 01:00:00') 
   or (dimension.mod >='2018-12-26 01:00:00' and dimension.mod <='2019-06-26 01:00:00');
```

So the first request is wrong. Could you help me ?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be a big help.  In addition, you might want to *simplify* the question, perhaps by only referring to one date instead of five.  Also, your question is a generic one about modifications.  But the code seems to be looking at particular date/times.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Inner joins allows you to select records where the data in all 5 tables was inserted/altered. But you need the records where the data is inserted/altered in at least one table - so you need FULL JOIN which is not supported by MySQL. Select modified records from each separate table. Then LEFT JOIN each separate to all another tables, then UNION the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you notice

```
JOIN table2 item 
    ON co.order_no = item.order_no
```

along with

```
or (item.ins >='2018-12-26 01:00:00' and item.ins <='2019-06-26 01:00:00') 
or (item.mod >='2018-12-26 01:00:00' and item.mod <='2019-06-26 01:00:00')
```

restricts the result of your first query to **only inserted / modified records of table2** which means you are matching with table2's inserted / modified rows with table3's inserted / modified rows with table4's...

which can give only smaller result.

Whereas the second query just depend on table3 giving 200 count.